# SQL Statement "invalid column name": how to build query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, select, clause

```
    string ID = "";
        if (Session["sID"] != null)
        {
            ID = Session["sID"].ToString();
            con.Open();

            string surveysr = "Select ShowResult from Survey where SurveyID=" + ID ;
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(surveysr, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
           .............
```

the error given was " Invalid column name 'S29' "
the problem was, the ID is just S29, without the single quote.
however, when the sql catch is with the ''.
any idea??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never NEVER **NEVER** use string concatenation to substitute values into your sql queries like that.  You want this:

```
string ID = "";
if (Session["sID"] != null)
{
    ID = Session["sID"].ToString();
    con.Open();

    string surveysr = "Select ShowResult from Survey where SurveyID= @ID";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(surveysr, con);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = ID;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

With your old code, what if I had managed to create an ID named `;DROP Table Survey;--`?

Comment: the ID is not an INT, since its start with an "S"
will give it a shot. thanks for the advice

Comment: Just noticed the "int" issue - try the updated code, and change the "3" in there to match the actual size of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help you :

```
string ID = "";
    if (Session["sID"] != null)
    {
        ID = CStr(Session["sID"]).ToString();
        con.Open();

        string surveysr = "Select ShowResult from Survey where SurveyID=" + ID ;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(surveysr, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
       .............
```

Comment: Still vulnerable to sql injection, and won't even solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
string surveysr = "Select ShowResult from Survey where SurveyID='" + ID + "'" ;
```

Comment: This may seem to work, but is still vulnerable to sql injection. It's the **wrong** way to do it.

Comment: too much paranoia, there is absolutely no mention of ID being an unsanitized variable coming from the wild web. a perfectly valid to-the-point answer to the question, certainly not worthy of your insecure moralizing

Comment: did you notice the extra single quote before the "?  try copy/paste?

Comment: That's still no reason not to do it with query parameters. Query parameters teach good habits and almost always perform better, while string concatenation encourages an insecure practice.

Comment: @agksmehx yo, at first its working. but now i just tried it again using ur code. but it shows the extra '' again..

Comment: the problem was with another line though when i want to Response.Redirect("PublicViewResultPage2.aspx?SurveyID='" + ID + "'");
the id have '' again. what should i do?

Comment: oh, in that line you need to remove the single ' on each side, so it should look like: SurveyID=" + ID);